# How to keep track of the process started in python and killing it when necessary?

Tags: python, command-line, kill-process

I have started a command line program in linux using python with the following command

```
  os.system()
```

I want to keep track of the program and kill it while necessary within the same python program.

Would be cool if somebody could tell the safest way of doing it.

Thanks

Comment: Avoid using `os.system`. The [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) addresses this need (and much more), so you should read its (fine) documentation

Comment: Also the answer may depend on your OS.

Answer (score 2):

Use `subprocess.Popen` and `Popen.pid`, you can get the pid of the process you started.

Like this:

```
>>> s = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/sleep"," 100 &"])
>>> print s.pid
34934
```

In the other shell, run `ps -ef|grep sleep`, you can see:

```
WKPlus@mac:~/workspace/test >ps -ef|grep sleep
  501 34934 34904   0 10:53下午 ttys000    0:00.00 /bin/sleep  100 &
  501 34938   238   0 10:54下午 ttys002    0:00.00 grep sleep
```

Yes, `s.pid` is exactly the pid of the process you just started.

And, be careful not to add an `shell=True` to the `subprocess.Popen(["/bin/sleep"," 100 &"])`, or you will get the pid of a shell, which is the parent process of `/bin/sleep`. 
[The official explanation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.pid) for this:

```
Note that if you set the shell argument to True, this is the process ID of the spawned shell.
```

Once you got the `pid`, you can kill the specified process by using `os.kill(pid)` after that.

Comment: except use `os.kill(pid)` instead of relying on `os.system`

Comment: @JoshG79 Oh, yes, `os.kill` is better. I used `os.system` just because the OPs mentioned it. I will change that.